# Can't ping channel - discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm able to tag a user like this `<@524679333387741697>`, but I haven't been able to ping a channel to alert users doing the same time with the channelId. When I try that with a channel it just outputs `<@222223387741697>`
I know how to link a channel like <#1059573997458698240>, but how can I ping the channel like @channel not #channel?

Comment: This is not a discord feature, nor has it ever been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only mention Roles and users with `@role`. `@channel` hasn't, and will never be a feature. The most you can do is ping the role that has access to the channel. Otherwise, you can link a channel with `#channel` as you mentioned correctly.